# What exactly happened in 1974 during the invasion of Cyprus by the Turks?

Tags: turkey, greece, invasion, cyprus

This is very recent history and I want to make up my opinion on this. What exactly happened during the invasion of Cyprus in 1974 from Turkey? There are 2 sides of this story but historically which events can be validated? What I know is that there was a Turkish minority in Cyprus and something happened with the Greek population there which made Turkey invade Cyprus. When I search it up on the Internet I only find Greeks and Turkish people arguing about who is right. Obviously since both sides are biased, it isn't a good source of info. So what exactly happened?

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)  What is wrong with the summary on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkish_invasion_of_Cyprus)?